# Setting up linq to sql context

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to avoid a 3 part join, and I want to get directly to my 3rd tables name, but Im new to linq to sql and Im not sure how I need to set everything up to work correctly. An example of what i am doing but dont want to do is:

```
from x in currentLogs
join y in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
on x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID equals y.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID
join cat in cDataContext.Categories
on y.CategoryID equals cat.CategoryID
where x.Response != 0 && cat.StorefrontID==storeID
select x).Count();
```

What i want to do is:

```
from x in currentLogs
join y in cDataContext.Categories
on x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID equals y.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMapping.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID
where x.Response != 0 && y.StorefrontID==storeID
select x).Count();
```

but i get an error when

```
cat.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMapping.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID
```

is returned by my autogenerated dbml, Sequence is more than one entity.

My layout Looks like: [image: DataContext]

DownloadLog to cccmapping is a one to one, everything else is a one to many. I may have it messed up a bit, but downloadlog logs a cccMapping, where as the cccmapping has permutations of countrys categories and categorytypes, each permutation is unique. Not sure if that makes  the mapping table a one to one, or one to many. Ether way did i set up my context right to do what im trying to do?

Comment: why are you trying to avoid a 3 table join? Under the scenes that's going to have to happen anyway

Comment: It might be petty, but code simplicty/readability. If cccMappings has a category, and that category has a name, it makes sense in code to say cccMappings.categories.select(...).Name

Comment: Why don't you use the navigation properties like `Category.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings` that should be in the class model? You probably don't need one single join at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your setup it appears that you should be able to use the navigation properties. So something along these lines should work.

```
currentLogs
    .Where(log => log.Response != 0 && 
        log.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
            .Any(map => map.Categories
                .Any(cat => cat.StoreFrontID == storeID))).Count();
```